# Fix Fn-keys for keyboard illumination on Samsung Notebook 9 Spin (NP940X3L)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, keyboard

I've tried following the [Ubuntu hotkeys/media keys troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting) and `/usr/share/doc/udev/README.keymap.txt.gz` to make the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work. After copying the map file and modifying `/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules` I get the correct key names from `sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event4`, but none of them do anything at all.

How do I make sure that at least `wlan` and `kbdillumup`/`kbdillumdown` work?

```
$ /lib/udev/findkeyboards
AT keyboard: input/event4
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/sys_vendor
SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name
90X3A
```

`samsung-90x3a` map file:

```
0xCE prog1 # Fn+F1 Unknown
0x8D prog3 # Fn+F6 Economy mode
0x97 kbdillumdown # Fn+F7 Keyboard background light down
0x96 kbdillumup # Fn+F8 Keyboard background light up
0xD5 wlan # Fn+F12 Wifi on/off
```

[`$ udevadm info --export-db`](http://pastebin.com/HWHxW2xE)

**Update**: The information below will be from Arch Linux since I no longer have Ubuntu.

`xdotool key XF86KbdBrightnessUp` prints nothing, but returns with exit code 0. I'm not sure if that means anything.

`acpi_listen` prints nothing when pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: You can test whether your kernel is supporting these functions on your laptop with `xdotool`.  Try `xdotool key XF86KbdBrightnessUp` and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: what `acpi-listen` give you when you type `Fn+f7` ?

Comment: @chirp - did you try the [jablonskis tutorial](http://jablonskis.org/2012/linux-and-samsung-series-laptop-9-fn-keys/). Did that not solve the issue for you?

Comment: here is how you associate a keypress to a command with KDE: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Configure_your_multimedia_keys

Comment: I am guessing you are UEFI booting?

Comment: I never did on Ubuntu, but now I am.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102261/how-to-enable-fn-keys-on-samsung-900x-in-arch-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody finally found the next best thing. To [turn off the backlight](https://bugzilla.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109178#c11), run this:

```
sudo chattr -i /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/KBDBacklitLvl-5af56f53-985c-47d5-920c-f1c531d06852
echo 0700000000 | xxd -plain -revert | sudo tee /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/KBDBacklitLvl-5af56f53-985c-47d5-920c-f1c531d06852
sudo chattr +i /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/KBDBacklitLvl-5af56f53-985c-47d5-920c-f1c531d06852
```

and then reboot. To set the illumination low, medium or high, replace `0700000000` in the above with `0700000001`, `0700000002` or `0700000003`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often, to get the backlight adjustment to work, you need to edit your GRUB configuration to contain the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

That worked for enabling backlight controls on most of my laptops.