# How to enable Fn keys on Samsung 900X in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, samsung

The only one which works is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (toggle touchpad), presumably because `xf86-input-synaptics` is installed. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> prints a literal plus/minus sign ("±").

Installing [`samsung-tools`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/samsung-tools/) and rebooting did not help.

A [forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=121564) indicates that it might have worked out of the box before, but not since 2011. Could it be [related to UEFI](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147094)?

**[Follow-up question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315178/3645) after changing to BIOS mode.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is related to UEFI (if you choose to boot in that mode). These laptops were being bricked by a write to NVRAM (see this [thread on the Arch boards for background](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157196)); consequently, the `samsung_laptop` module is blocked from loading in UEFI mode, taking some of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key functionality went with it, most notably:

- <kbd>F12</kbd> for `rfkill`
- <kbd>F11</kbd> for CPU management
- <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> for the keyboard backlighting

All of the remaining <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys do show up with either `xev` or `showkey` and can be enabled either by your DE, or if you run a lightweight setup, some simple scripts.

Comment: Ouch! I'm glad mine didn't get bricked yet. Will change to BIOS boot ASAP. Considering that it was much more complicated to set up and *still* has more problems than BIOS boot, I don't see why it's recommended.

Comment: FWIW: I have been UEFI booting mine since Dec, and apart from a few kernel panics before I blacklisted that module, I have had no issues...

Comment: Thanks; will see if it remains as stable as it is otherwise.