# How to enable monitor brightness keyboard shortcuts on Samsung 90X3A?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, brightness

I've set up a Samsung 90X3A [from scratch](https://github.com/l0b0/root) (using BIOS boot to avoid a known [related issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102261/3645)), and I'm having trouble enabling the screen brightness keys (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>).

The current state:

- Manually setting the brightness works:

  ```
  sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <<< 1000
  sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness <<< 50
  ```
- `xbacklight` works:

  ```
  $ xbacklight -get
  100.000000
  ```
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> are detected properly:

  ```
  $ sudo evtest /dev/input/event0
    Input driver version is 1.0.1
  Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x1 product 0x1 version 0xab41
  Input device name: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Supported events:
  […]
  Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
  Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
  […]
  Event: time […], type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 89
  Event: time […], type 1 (EV_KEY), code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN), value 1
  Event: time […], -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
  Event: time […], type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 89
  Event: time […], type 1 (EV_KEY), code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN), value 0
  Event: time […], -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
  Event: time […], type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 88
  Event: time […], type 1 (EV_KEY), code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP), value 1
  Event: time […], -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
  Event: time […], type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 88
  Event: time […], type 1 (EV_KEY), code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP), value 0
  Event: time […], -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
  ```
- ACPId is running:

  ```
  $ systemctl is-active acpid
  active
  ```
- `xmodmap` doesn't agree with `evtest` (but see below for attempted workaround):

  ```
  $ xmodmap -pke | egrep '224|225'
  keycode 224 = XF86Messenger NoSymbol XF86Messenger
  keycode 225 = XF86Search NoSymbol XF86Search
  ```

However, the screen brightness does not change.

There are heaps of advice around for dealing with this and similar issues. Here's what I've already tried:

- All the [recommended `acpi_osi` settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Backlight_is_not_adjustable), verified using `cat /proc/cmdline`.
- [`acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`](https://askubuntu.com/a/169953/10371)
- [Blacklisting `samsung_laptop`](https://askubuntu.com/a/169953/10371), verified using `lsmod | grep samsung_laptop`.
- [Adding the following to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#xbacklight):

  ```
  Section "Device"
      Identifier  "Card0"
      Driver      "intel"
      Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
  EndSection
  ```
- Setting `xmodmap` bindings:

  ```
  $ xmodmap -e 'keycode 224 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown'
  $ xmodmap -e 'keycode 225 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp'
  ```

Other possibly relevant system information:

- X process tree:

  ```
  $ ps af -e --format user,cmd | sed "s/$USER/user  /g"
  USER     CMD
  […]
  root     /usr/bin/lightdm
  root      \_ /usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
  root      \_ lightdm --session-child 13 20
  user          \_ awesome
  user              \_ logger --priority user notice --tag xprofile-user
  user              \_ logger --priority user error --tag xprofile-user
  user              \_ xss-lock slock
  user              \_ cbatticon
  ```

Comment: Only one `acpi_video0` xor `intel_backlight` should be able to set the brightness, not both.  You should then be able to add something like `Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"` (or acpi) to xorg.conf.  I suspect that xorg is using the one that does not work.

Comment: *Both* of them work,  as does xbacklight, even after adding the backlight option to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. And no warnings or errors in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. So that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Hmm... it is the first time I see two /sys controls working.  Random guessing now:  `xmodmap -pke | egrep '224|225'`? and whether [this works](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/light/)?  (it is what I use, and the author is currently implementing the keyboard usage, look in the github issues for that)

Comment: `keycode 224 = XF86Messenger NoSymbol XF86Messenger`, `keycode 225 = XF86Search NoSymbol XF86Search`

Comment: Wow!  That doesn't seem right.  It seems to contradict your `evtest`. My guess is that `xmodmap -e 'keycode 224 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown'` and `xmodmap -e 'keycode 225 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp'`  have a good chance of making the keys work as they should.

Comment: Nope. And I double checked the output of both `xmodmap` and `evtest` before running them.

Comment: Hmm... I'm clueless.  I would try to use my WM's keybindings to get the functionality through `xbacklight -set`.  But i use Xmonad, so it is easy for me.  I believe i3 has similar functionality but not so sure about other WMs.

Answer (score 2):

For now I'm working around this by [hardcoding commands to handle the XF86 events in Awesome WM](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/f679483328cf1347f90f72ba4872213764663816):

```
awful.key({}, "XF86MonBrightnessDown", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("xbacklight -dec 5") end),
awful.key({}, "XF86MonBrightnessUp", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("xbacklight -inc 5") end),
```

I'm still holding out for a solution to handle this independently of the window manager.

Comment: You will need *some* program to process the keys, so you might as well use the window manager that's already running ... or why do you prefer a different program that you'd have to run additionally?

Comment: I would expect the OS to handle this without *any* manual configuration.

Comment: The *OS* doesn't handle it at all (and why should it? Linux runs fine without any sort of graphics display or keyboard). Some *desktop environments* handle it by running additional programs (without any manual configuration, in most cases), but you don't seem to have those installed.

Comment: I don't have to implement my own boot loader. I don't have to set up my own compose key table. I don't have to create a colour scheme for `top`. And I *should not* have to bind extremely common keyboard shortcuts to commands. I would *definitely* expect this to be part of a very minimal working X desktop system.

Comment: Well, it *is* part of the bigger desktop systems. But if you don't run these, but use your own choice of window manager instead (which I do, too), and nobody wrote that part for that particular window manager (which is some effort, because there's lots of variations concerning backlight handling), then it's not there. And running an *additional* program that may conflict with the WM isn't the solution. :-) It's open source, contact the maintainers of Awesome WM and suggest to include it in the standard configuration. Which they probably won't do, because `xbacklight` doesn't work everywhere.